# Python - initiate empty dataframe and populate from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Working with python pandas 0.19.

I want to create a new dataframe (df2) as a subset of an existing dataframe (df1).  df1 looks like this:

```
In [1]: df1.head()
Out [1]:
    col1_name    col2_name    col3_name
0          23           42           55
1          27           55           57
2          52           20           52
3          99           18           53   
4          65           32           51
```

The logic is:

```
df2 = []

for i in range(0,N):
    loc = some complicated logic
    df1_sub = df1.ix[loc,]
    df2.append(df1_sub)

df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_records(df2)
```

The result df2 is indeed a dataframe, but the content is all comprised of column names of df1.  It looks like this:

```
In [2]: df2.head()
Out [2]:
    col1_name    col2_name    col3_name
0   col1_name    col2_name    col3_name
1   col1_name    col2_name    col3_name
2   col1_name    col2_name    col3_name
3   col1_name    col2_name    col3_name
4   col1_name    col2_name    col3_name
```

I know it's probably related to the conversion from list to dataframe but I'm not sure what exactly I'm missing here.  Or is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: please include `df1.head()` and final result that you want. That makes the problem easier to understand.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you are asking but there are many things that need to be addressed.  Do not use `.ix` unless absolutely necessary. You shouldn't have to create a list of dataframes to do this but if you do, the last line should be changed to `pd.concat(df2)`. Please provide more info as it might be possible to not use a for loop to construct the logic. Also the name `df2` implies you have a DataFrame. Use something like `df_list` instead.

Comment: in the for loop check the value of loc, it may tell you if there is something wrong

Comment: @ Ted Petrou  pd.concat(df2) is the way to go. The logic is indeed complicated.  I'll have to even do a while loop within the for loop: take a slice from df1 called df1_sub, take out one row of df1_sub if a condition is met, and check the remaining df1_sub until the condition is no longer met.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Ted Petrou, the solution is simply:

```
pd.concat(df2)
```

I was confused by the data type of df2.

It is impossible, given the logic within the for loop, to directly select df1 using some index.

Answer (score 0):

How about just slice the dataframe?

```
import pandas as pd
DF1 = pd.DataFrame()
DF1['x'] = ['a','b','c','a','c','b']
DF1['y'] = [1,3,2,-1,-2,-3]

DF2 = DF1[[(x == 'a' and y > 0) for x,y in zip(DF1['x'], DF1['y'])]]
```

This should be way more efficient than appending. DF1[Complicated Condition] takes any Boolean arguement

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of pandas' (actually numpy's) masked arrays.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'b': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
                    'c': [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]})

#      a  b   c
#   0  1  a  10
#   1  2  b  11
#   2  3  c  12
#   3  4  d  13
#   4  5  e  14
```

Let's assume that `df2` should be a subset of `df1`: it should have columns `b` and `c` and only the rows where column `a` has an even value:

```
df2 = df1[df1['a'] % 2 == 0][['b', 'c']]
#    b   c
# 1  b  11
# 3  d  13
```